# how to scan non-default SSH port

Tags: ubuntu, nmap

for example port SSH is 4020

```
nmap 192.168.1.1 -sV
```

The result is :

PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
25/tcp   open  smtp    Postfix smtpd

where is SSH port ?

I try command below to test ssh

```
ssh myuser@192.168.1.1 -p4020
```

and its works.

FYI:
nmap version : Nmap version 6.40
Ubuntu Server : 14.04

Thanks

Comment: how about `nmap 192.168.1.1 -p4020` ? (is that what you want?)

Comment: nmap 192.168.1.1 -p4020 the result is 4020/tcp closed unknown

Comment: is your ssh command meant to be ssh -p 4020  (so a space between the -p and the 4020, whereas with nmap no space).  So, check that ssh was really connecting to port 4020 when you missed the space. And see if ssh still works with -p 4020 and then try nmap ip -p4020

Comment: hmm actually ssh -p works with or without the space so my previous comment can't be it..   Is the port coming up as closed whether you ssh to it or not?

Comment: when I connect ssh to it or dont connect to it, nmap doesnt listing about ssh service.

Comment: I think when you don't specify a port `nmap 192.168.1.1`  it doesn't scan all ports, and so it didn't check port 4020.  Hence when you specified -p4020 then it found it.http://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html "By default, Nmap scans the most common 1,000 ports for each protocol."     Try this then... to specify all ports  do `-p1-65535`  It should show as open then, as nmap will then check it, but Also, are you finding -sV to be of any use when the port is non-default i.e. -p4020?

Comment: +1, nmap 192.168.1.1 -p1-65535 , will display the open ports, in this case port 4020, but for the service column display "unknown". Ok thank @barlop

Comment: ops, sorry for your comment nmap 192.168.1.1 -p4020 it's works, my fault when testing it

Comment: so do you find -sV never works?  I recall having issues with -sV myself, Doing `nc 192.168.1.1 4020 <ENTER>`  shows some text that you can recognize "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7"   and you can do `CTRL-C`

Comment: at this time -sV never works for me ? why ? but using nc 192.168.1.1 4020  very fast that shows this text "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1"

Comment: I have the exact same question re -sV not working. You could ask on the nmap mailing list and report back here. I  think one time I tried -sV I found it was just reporting back whatever the default port was. So if I put an ssh server on port 25 then it was saying smtp! Also when you do -p1-65535 or multiple ports, you could add -v so it reports back as it does it. And -T5 makes it a little bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

The port 4020 is not scanned by default by Nmap (only the 1000 most frequently found are).

You can try: `nmap -sV -p 4020 192.168.1.1`.